# Oracle join dual daterange

Tags: sql, oracle, join, dual-table

I'm trying to place data into a date range from a dual query. The outcome should look like this:

```
SINGLEDAY       FLAG
01-NOV-2016     1
02-NOV-2016     -
03-NOV-2016     -
04-NOV-2016     1
05-NOV-2016     -
```

For the list of days I'm using

```
select (to_date('11.2016','mm.yyyy')+level-1) as SINGLEDAY
from dual
connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date('11.2016','mm.yyyy')),'DD')
```

But how do I join content of my table xyz with the outcome? table xyz should be connected by a DATE_OF_SERVICE (date)column. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you get 01-NOV from a query where you select to_date(09.2016)? In your locale the ninth month is November? More likely you are misstating the facts. Not cool!

Comment: Sorry mathguy, you're right with the 09.2016. I changed it to 11.2016. Anyway. According to the 01-NOV: The date is given by default from my oracle instance. It doesn't matter which format I render it in. The connect seem to handle it this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a `left join` on your query.  Assuming at most one row in your table for each date:

```
with d as (
      select (to_date('09.2016','mm.yyyy')+level-1) as singleday
      from dual
      connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date('09.2016', 'mm.yyyy')), 'DD')
     )
select t.singleday,
       (case when t.date_of_service is not null then 1 end) as flag
from d left join
     t
     on d.singleday = t.date_of_service
order by d.singleday;
```

If there are multiples, then perhaps you what `group by`:

```
with d as (
      select (to_date('09.2016','mm.yyyy')+level-1) as singleday
      from dual
      connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date('09.2016', 'mm.yyyy')), 'DD')
     )
select t.singleday, count(t.date_of_service) as cnt
from d left join
     t
     on d.singleday = t.date_of_service
group by d.singleday
order by d.singleday;
```